# Identifying the correct line of a text file using re.compile

Tags: python, regex, text, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I'm new to processing text files using Python and I got stuck on finding the correct line in a text file.

Looking at the image, I need to find a way that the block returns to me the line which contains the words:

'***New packet was received***' + *something in between* + *the string stored in the variable **stcrouter_line***. (See picture).

Just with the variable, it returns 3 lines, which is correct in previously. Now, I just need to get the second line (with pattern above).

I believe I need the correct expression on the first line of the block:

`line_regex = re.compile(stcrouter_line)`.

I'm not sure how to formulate this. Can anyone help me out, please?

[image]

Comment: Try `line_regex = re.compile('New packet was received' + r'.*?' + stcrouter_line)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify your code to:

```
line_regex = re.compile('New packet was received' + r'.*?' + stcrouter_line)
```

This is to match:

- `New packet was received`    match the text literally
- `r'.*?`     raw-string containing the regex `.*?` that will match any
  texts in between the literal string above and your existing pattern.
  With `?` after `*` to make it the shortest match so that the match
  will not overshoot to your existing pattern.
- `stcrouter_line`    your existing pattern

Comment: That worked perfectly. Many thanks, not only for providing the solution but also for explaining it to me!
Amazing!